# Pattern matching using Cases: why does this fail?

Tags: pattern-matching

I have objects that look like, for example:

```
F2 = 2 d[x] ^ d[y] + 3 d[x] ^ d[z]
```

where `^` is `Wedge` (and not exponentiation). The variables inside of `d[...]` are not known beforehand and the number of terms is also not known; I would like to extract the coefficients that lie in front of these terms (here `2` and `3`). The real objects that I have to work with are enormous, so I would like to do this as efficiently as possible, so I try to extract what differentials I have like this:

```
Cases[ Level[F2, 1] , _ d[a_] ^ d[b_] -> d[a] ^ d[b] ]
```

This returns: `{ d[x] ^ d[y], d[x] ^ d[z] }`. So, now I can use `Coefficient` and all is well.

However, if I have an object like this:

```
F2 = 2 d[x] ^ d[y] + 3 e[1] ^ e[2]
```

I would like to be returned the list: `{ d[x] ^ d[y], e[1] ^ e[2] }`; so, I try:

```
Cases[ Level[F2, 1] , _ d1_[a_] ^ d2_[b_] -> d1[a] ^ d2[b] ]
```

But this does not work. It returns an empty list. Why? And is there a way to make this work?

**Edit**

So, contrary to my claim, this does actually work as intended, except that an expression like:

```
F2 = d[x] ^ d[y]
```

returns an empty list. I naively expected the code I wrote above to handle an implicit coefficient as well as explicit ones. I needed to modify my code to:

```
Cases[ Level[F2, 1] , _ d1_[a_] ^ d2_[b_] | d1_[a_] ^ d2_[b_] -> d1[a] ^ d2[b] ]
```

Thanks for the help! I'll probably delete the question in due course...

Comment: Your example works on my machine. Try to either remove any definitions you have for `d1`, `d2`, `a` and `b`, or use `:>` instead of `->`.

Comment: It works for me, too.

Comment: Hang on. Let me see if I'm being dumb...

Comment: The `^` is `Wedge` and not exponentiation. It seems to work with exponentiation but not `Wedge` on my system. Sorry, I don't know how to format that in the question...

Comment: Still works here :p

Comment: It works for me too. Did you try evaluating only those two rows immediately after resetting the kernel?

Comment: Did you, by any chance, use exponentiation in your last line of code (in `Cases`)? Because if I use exponentiation I do get an empty list, while using `Wedge` returns the desired terms.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the problem the user is experiencing can not be reproduced by others.

Comment: I did not read that as `Wedge`! Anyway, I think `Cases[F2, Wedge[__], Infinity]` should work on everything except the bare expression `Wedge[d[x], d[y]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Is it not much easier and faster to simply use the following?

```
List@@F2/._Wedge->1
```

A possible solution for the more general problem described in the comments would (perhabs) be:

```
Replace[F2, a_*w_Wedge -> CustomSimplify[a]*w, {1}]
```

which applies some custom simplifications to the coefficients of the `Wedge`-products. One can change the pattern to `a_.` if the coefficient `1` should also be transformed.

Comment: Yes, but my question is a simplified version of my real needs :) I need to simplify the expressions but Mathematica finds simplifying p-forms very difficult to do, so my strategy is to extract coefficients, simplify them individually and then **recombine** them; so, I need to track what the coefficients are in front of also. Probably I'm still doing it inefficiently, though...

Comment: In effect, for `F2` above, what I need is something like: `Simplify[2] d[x] ^ d[y] + Simplify[3] d[x] ^ d[z]`. But where the actual coefficients are functions of the variables `x, y, z, ...` and not just `2` and `3` :)

Comment: I changed my reply a bit. Those patterns with default values are neat way to simplify code, see the tutorial on Patterns and Transformation Rules.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! I'm going to delete the question soon, but thanks for the suggestion!